# sequelize raw query column doesn't exist

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Im trying to use a raw query but im getting the error.
Why does it think test is a column name?

column "test" does not exist

```
module.exports = {

  getUser(req, res){
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM Users As Users WHERE Users.username = "test"'
    //Get the username of the user
    //Search the Users_matches databse for their username and join it with the
    db.sequelize.query(sql, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(result => {
      return res.status(201).send({
        result
      });
    })
}
```

Comment: Standard SQL uses single quote for string literals, double quotes are for identifier (such as table and column names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the value 'test'. This works

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
});

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => {
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM "Users" as "Users" WHERE username = \'test\'';
    sequelize.query(sql, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  });
```